# WPF Dependency property binding breaks and always uses the default value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, prism

I have a dependency property defined as below. It is defined in xaml.cs of Childusercontrol. It always uses the **default value of RGB(255,0,0) ie. Red**.

```
public Color ForeColor
{
    get {return (Color)this.GetValue(ForeColorProperty); }
    set {this.SetValue(ForeColorProperty, value);}
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ForeColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ForeColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Childusercontrol), new PropertyMetadata(Color.FromRgb(255,0,0), OnCurrentForeColorPropertyChanged));

private static void OnCurrentForeColorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{    
    Childusecontrol control = source as Childusecontrol;
    Color fcolor= (Color)e.NewValue;
}
```

The value is passed through xaml from parent usercontrol as

```
<UC:Childusercontrol ForeColor="{Binding ChildForeColor}"/>
```

> ChildForeColor is a property of type Color in ViewModel of ParentUserControl and is defined as below.

```
 private Color _ChildForeColor;
    public Color ChildForeColor 
    {
    get
    {
    return _ChildForeColor ;
    }
    set
    {
    if (_ChildForeColor  != value)
    {
    _ChildForeColor  = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(()=> ChildForeColor );
    }
    }
    }
```

And ChildForeColor  property is set as below, in the parentusercontrol's constructor.

> The value being passed as constructor parameter is **blue**.

```
public Parentusercontrol(System.Drawing.Color ForeColor)
{
ChildForeColor  = Color.FromRgb(ForeColor.R, ForeColor.B, ForeColor.G);
}
```

But, the `InitializeComponent();` of Parent control's xaml.cs clears the value of dependency property and hence, only the default value is used.

Do I have to change the definition of the dependency property? How to fix this bug?

Comment: can you show more wpf code? I.e.  where/how ChildForeColor is defined?  also perhaps what is done in "OnCurrentForeColorPropertyChanged"?

Comment: @DaClan its just a regular wpf property using Notifypropertychanged

Comment: Is it a regular dependency property or a normal CLR property calling INotifyProperty Changed when the property get changed?  How and when does it get changed?

Comment: When you declare the `<UC:Childusercontrol>` in XAML, are you also setting its `DataContext`?  If so, the binding on `ForeColor` will not use the parent's view model as its binding source.

Comment: @DaClan The property is set in the constructor of ParentUserControl's Viewmodel from a parameter to Blue. But it chooses the default Red color.

Comment: Is the DataContext of your ParentUserControl set correctly?

Comment: And can you post a little more code?  It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do.  What do you expect to see when ForeColor is changed?  You're also not doing anything with fcolor in the handler.

Comment: @TTat I want the color from parent usercontrol's ChildForeColor property to be set to dependency property of child usercontrol ie. ForeColor

Comment: You're talking about a `ChildForeColor` property in the "ViewModel of ParentUserControl" but in the Parentusercontrol constructor you're apparently setting a `ChildForeColor` directly on the control. That doesn't make sense. Or do you actually have two such properties?

Comment: @Clemens No its the same property. But how am I setting it on a control?

Comment: No idea. That is your code, so when you write `ChildForeColor = ...` in the constructor of Parentusercontrol, there must be such a property in that class. So where does the view model come into play?

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly fine for me!

1. ChildControl

   I gave the UserControl a Name in Xaml i.e

   ```
   <UserControl ... (all normal namespaces)... x:Name="Child">
       <Border>
          <Border.Background>
               <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ForeColor, ElementName=child}"/>
           </Border.Background>
       </Border>
   </UserControl>
   ```

   The property "ForeColor" is a dependency property as you defined it yourself.  This control works perfectly on its own too.
2. ParentControl

   I did the same as with ChildControl.  i.e. gave it a name.

   ```
   <UserControl ... (Usual NS)... x:Name="parent">
       <Border BorderThickness="2">
           <local:ChildUserControl Margin="5" ForeColor="{Binding ChildForeColor, ElementName=parent}"/>
           <Border.BorderBrush>
               <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ChildForeColor, ElementName=parent}"/>
           </Border.BorderBrush>
       </Border>
   </UserControl>
   ```

   This also works fine with testing the C# Class looks as follows

   ```
   public ParentUserControl(System.Drawing.Color c)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       Color c2 = Color.FromRgb(c.R, c.G, c.B);
       ChildForeColor = c2;

   }

   private Color _ChildForeColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
   public Color ChildForeColor
   {
       get { return _ChildForeColor; }
       set
       {
           if (value != _ChildForeColor)
           {
               _ChildForeColor = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(() => ChildForeColor);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   I have assigned the _ChildForeColor a value just for testing, but this is not needed.  Please note however that if you run a NotifyPropertyChanged event this cannot happen before InitializeComponent();  This I guess is because nothing yet has been initialized to listen to the change.  Therefore you have 2 options.  Remove OnPropertyChanged and assign color before InitializeComponent, or use OnPropertyChanged but only assign color after InitializeComponent.  The first solution will still work because the property value is changed before the components go and look for the value.
3. Window for using constructing the controls

   This is a bit more tricky as you have assigned a constructor that takes a variable. So my code looks as follows:

   ```
   public Control ParContent
   {
       get { return (ContentControl)GetValue(ParContentProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ParContentProperty, value); }
   }

   //Register Dependency ParContent Property
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ParContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ParContent", typeof(ContentControl), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata( ));

   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();  
      ParContent = new ParentUserControl(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
   }
   ```

   and in Xaml

   ```
   <Window ...Title="MainWindow" Height="478.784" Width="736.87" x:Name="win">
       <Grid>
           <local:ChildUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="122,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
           <ContentControl x:Name="Parent" Content="{Binding ParContent,ElementName=win}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="79" Width="93"/>
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```

As I said this worked perfectly fine by me and all the properties keep their values.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Make sure the parent's childForeColor has a color assigned to it especially when using ordinary properties.
2. If you use ordinary properties in Parent control make sure INotifyPropertyChange is called if the color is changed after Initialize (Which I guess you subscribe to already)
3. perhaps use FrameworkPropertyMetadata instead and then add flag AffectsRender - don't think this is the problem, but worth a shot
4. Play around with the Binding Mode - although I do not think this is the real issue either
5. If you are working with 2 x controls where 1 property is most likely going to inherit from another use Inherited properties rather - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx

Bottom line I have a suspicion that the Parent's "ChildForeColor" might be causing the problem as the above seems ok to me at first glance.

### EDIT

Try doing the following.  In xaml give your parent control a name x:name="Parent" then in the binding mode do this

```
<UC:Childusercontrol ForeColor="{Binding ChildForeColor, ElementName="Parent"}"/>
```

This should sort out any binding issues if the problem lies with the binding.

However you say "Parent control's xaml.cs clears the value of dependency property and hence, only the default value is used."  Which indicates that the problem is not with binding or with the child control as far as I can gather...

I also assumed you have stepped through the code so after you hit this

```
ChildForeColor  = Color.FromRgb(ForeColor.R, ForeColor.B, ForeColor.G);
```

ChildForeColor appears correct and then if you override OnInitialized() and evaluate the value of ChildForeColor after base.OnInitialized(e); has run the ForeColor is still unchanged?

**With this I also assume you have not removed InitializeComponent();** from the constructor, and InitializeComponent(); comes after ChildForeColor = ....!  In your constructor you do not show where InitializeComponent() is and I assumed it was just for easy reading purpose.

If ForeColor remained unchanged at this point and assuming base.OnInitialized is the first method that runs in OnInitialized.  Then Initialization is not the problem, then the alternative suggestion is to change ChildForeColor to a proper dependency property:

```
public Color ChildForeColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ChildForeColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildForeColorProperty, value); }
    }

    //Register Dependency ChildForeColor Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildForeColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChildForeColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ParentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
```

and see if that changes it.

Comment: I haven't tried overriding OnInitialized. Can you give me somnme links to blogposts explain lifecycle of wpf usercontrol with respect to events? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221(v=vs.110).aspx here I can find only Initialized, loaded and unloaded and they don't help.

Comment: hmm... I am not sure about links or posts sorry, perhaps someone else here might assist with that.